# Apache Tomcat 8 port does not change after editing server.xml

Tags: apache, tomcat8

[This tutorial](http://to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80) taught me how to change port number.

Here's what I did:

- cd /usr/local/apache-tomcat8/conf
- vim server.xml
- Search "Connector port"
- Replace "8080" by '8082'
- Restart tomcat server.

But the browser only worked for port 8080, not for 8082.

What went wrong?

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where went wrong.

It is necessary to run **bin/shutdown.sh** BEFORE running **startup.sh**.